# How should we create parent QModelIndex while calling beginInsertRows(parent, first, last)?

Tags: qt, listview, models, qml, qmodelindex

It is more concrete version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15657830/qml-listview-does-not-update-information-after-endinsertrows).

I want to report to the view that I'm going to insert some rows to my model. There are two ways to call `beginInsertRows`:

```
beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), first, last)
```

and

```
beginInsertRows(createIndex(-1,-1), first, last)
```

There is a difference: in the 2nd variant `QModelIndex` will store pointer to our model inside itself. And in Qml internals:

```
void QQuickVisualDataModel::_q_rowsInserted(const QModelIndex &parent, int begin, int end)
{
    Q_D(QQuickVisualDataModel);
    qDebug() << "d->m_adaptorModel.rootIndex = " << d->m_adaptorModel.rootIndex;
    if (parent == d->m_adaptorModel.rootIndex)
        _q_itemsInserted(begin, end - begin + 1);
}
```

the body of `if` statement will not be executed because it seems that `rootIndex` always does not store pointer to the model (i.e. it stores NULL instead)

I have created [test Qt5 application](https://github.com/Kakadu/qml-test-3)

So, my question is:
**Is it bug or feature?** Have somebody tried this buggy invocation before me?

Comment: Perhaps it is a bug.  I'd suggest using index() for this use case http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractitemmodel.html#index

Comment: Yeah, I have added a condition `if (row==-1||column==-1) return QModelIndex() else return createIndex(row,column)` and it helps. But it does not close my question.